# Oracle EBS installation in windows operating system

Tags: oracle-ebs

How to install oracle ebs in windows system when googling everything points to the oracle vm instance of linux but i want to install it in windows os. I downloaded the required zip (Oracle E-Business Suite 12.2.12) and how to install with this zip and configure EBS. Thanks in advance
PS: I tried googling and found only vm installation which is linux installation.[image]

Downloaded this package oracle ebs

Comment: That's described in **E-Business Suite Installation Guide** (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/doc.122/e22950/toc.htm)

Comment: It does mention having rapid installation files will be listed when downloading but i cant see that zip listed in my listing

Comment: So, there's no **rapidwiz.cmd** file anywhere in EBS folders?